# How to improve the quality of my shadows?

Tags: opengl, rendering

First, a screenshot:

[image]

As you can see, the tops of the shadows look OK (if you look at the dirt where the tops of the shrubs are projected, it looks more or less correct), but the base of the shadows is way off.

The bottom left corner of the image shows the shadow map I computed. It's a depth-map from the POV of the light, which is also where my character is standing.

Here's another shot, from a different angle:

[image]

Any ideas what might be causing it to come out like this? Is the depth of the shrub face too similar to the depth of the ground directly behind it, perhaps? If so, how do I get around that?

I'll post the fragment shader below, leave a comment if there's anything else you need to see.

### Fragment Shader

```
#version 330

in vec2 TexCoord0;
in vec3 Tint0;
in vec4 WorldPos;
in vec4 LightPos;

out vec4 FragColor;

uniform sampler2D TexSampler;
uniform sampler2D ShadowSampler;
uniform bool Blend;

const int MAX_LIGHTS = 16;
uniform int NumLights;
uniform vec3 Lights[MAX_LIGHTS];
const float lightRadius = 100;

float distSq(vec3 v1, vec3 v2) {
    vec3 d = v1-v2;
    return dot(d,d);
}

float CalcShadowFactor(vec4 LightSpacePos)
{
    vec3 ProjCoords = LightSpacePos.xyz / LightSpacePos.w;
    vec2 UVCoords;
    UVCoords.x = 0.5 * ProjCoords.x + 0.5;
    UVCoords.y = 0.5 * ProjCoords.y + 0.5;
    float Depth = texture(ShadowSampler, UVCoords).x;
    if (Depth < (ProjCoords.z + 0.0001))
        return 0.5;
    else
        return 1.0;
}

void main()
{
    float scale;

    FragColor = texture2D(TexSampler, TexCoord0.xy);

    // transparency
    if(!Blend && FragColor.a < 0.5) discard;

    // biome blending
    FragColor *= vec4(Tint0, 1.0f);

    // fog
    float depth = gl_FragCoord.z / gl_FragCoord.w;
    if(depth>20) {
        scale = clamp(1.2-15/(depth-19),0,1);
        vec3 destColor = vec3(0.671,0.792,1.00);
        vec3 colorDist = destColor - FragColor.xyz;
        FragColor.xyz += colorDist*scale;
    }

    // lighting
    scale = 0.30;
    for(int i=0; i<NumLights; ++i) {
        float dist = distSq(WorldPos.xyz, Lights[i]);
        if(dist < lightRadius) {
            scale += (lightRadius-dist)/lightRadius;
        }
    }

    scale *= CalcShadowFactor(LightPos);
    FragColor.xyz *= clamp(scale,0,1.5);
}
```

---

I'm fairly certain this is an offset problem. My shadows look to be about 1 block off, but I can't figure out how to shift them, nor what's causing them to be off.

[image]

---

Looks like "[depth map bias](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache:gG7ELVe6tCUJ:developer.download.nvidia.com/assets/gamedev/docs/ShadowMaps_CEDEC_E.pdf+&hl=en&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESgeqkTW3FimsiRfHOpUEtCNMAZT-fzPOlWH_YZ4dx5vAhx304bAw8gSYznH3vVMUBu_0Zff_fwYZ-K_S4jLKZjeB6FNjfV7Rcs1Nk7KjQQYyx9m2SeNeMAEg0pqL42WOmA3nkdJ&sig=AHIEtbQ6OS2Edy6yqmjkA5TBq8tl_UqZYQ&pli=1)" actually:

[image]

Not exactly sure how to set this....do I just call [glPolygonOffset](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glPolygonOffset.xml) before rendering the scene? Will try it...

Setting `glPolygonOffset` to 100,100 amplifies the problem:

[image]

I set this just before rendering the shadow map:

```
GL.Enable(EnableCap.PolygonOffsetFill);
GL.PolygonOffset(100f, 100.0f);
```

And then disabled it again. I'm not sure if that's how I'm supposed to do it. Increasing the values amplifies the problem....decreasing them to below 1 doesn't seem to improve it though.

Notice also how the shadow map in the lower left changed.

### Vertex Shader

```
#version 330

layout(location = 0) in vec3 Position;

layout(location = 1) in vec2 TexCoord;
layout(location = 2) in mat4 Transform;
layout(location = 6) in vec4 TexSrc; // x=x, y=y, z=width, w=height
layout(location = 7) in vec3 Tint; // x=R, y=G, z=B

uniform mat4 ProjectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 LightMatrix;

out vec2 TexCoord0;
out vec3 Tint0;
out vec4 WorldPos;
out vec4 LightPos;

void main()
{
    WorldPos = Transform * vec4(Position, 1.0);
    gl_Position = ProjectionMatrix * WorldPos;
    LightPos = LightMatrix * WorldPos;
    TexCoord0 = vec2(TexSrc.x+TexCoord.x*TexSrc.z, TexSrc.y+TexCoord.y*TexSrc.w); 
    Tint0 = Tint;
}
```

Comment: So the camera is located in the person's head. On top is the miner's lamp. The shadow maps then should view the scene's depth from a slightly upraised position -

Comment: @StefanHanke: Not sure what you mean by "slightly upraised". Is this just an observation, or can I do something with that?

Comment: _Observation_. Since I never implemented shadow mapping, I'm not sure on the following: the shadow map is generated using the position of the light. Since this is on the head of the person, I would expect that the view is from above. Judging by the images, the lamp appears to be lower than the head. So, perhaps something with the light matrices? Sorry if this is totally bogus...

Comment: @StefanHanke: Your observation is correct. The lamp is a bit lower than the head; I believe the "miner's light" expression just means the light is *close* to camera, not that is actually *directly* above, or at the exact same point.

Comment: Would you mind posting the vertex shader?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While world-aligned cascaded shadow maps are great and used in most new games out there, it's not related to why your shadows have a strange offset with your current implementation.

Actually, it looks like you're sampling from the correct texels on the shadow map just on where the shadows that are occurring are exactly where you'd expect them to be, however your comparison is off.

I've added some comments to your code:

```
vec3 ProjCoords = LightSpacePos.xyz / LightSpacePos.w; // So far so good...
vec2 UVCoords;
UVCoords.x = 0.5 * ProjCoords.x + 0.5; // Right, you're converting X and Y from clip
UVCoords.y = 0.5 * ProjCoords.y + 0.5; // space to texel space...
float Depth = texture(ShadowSampler, UVCoords).x; // I expect we sample a value in [0,1]
if (Depth < (ProjCoords.z + 0.0001)) // Uhoh, we never converted Z's clip space to [0,1]
    return 0.5;
else
    return 1.0;
```

So, I suspect you want to compare to `ProjCoords.z * 0.5 + 0.5`:

```
if (Depth < (ProjCoords.z * 0.5 + 0.5 + 0.0001))
    return 0.5;
else
    return 1.0;
```

Also, that bias factor makes me nervous. Better yet, just take it out for now and deal with it once you get the shadows appearing in the right spots:

```
const float bias = 0.0;
if (Depth < (ProjCoords.z * 0.5 + 0.5 + bias))
    return 0.5;
else
    return 1.0;
```

I might not be entirely right about how to transform ProjCoords.z to match the sampled value, however this is likely the issue. Also, if you do move to cascaded shadow maps (I recommend world-aligned) I'd strongly recommend drawing frustums representing where each shadow map is viewing -- it makes debugging a whole lot easier.

Comment: You sir, are a genius! It [works pretty well now](http://i.imgur.com/Pnkfo.png). The bias [was needed](http://i.imgur.com/mNli4.png); took a bit of fiddling but `-0.0005` seems to work pretty well.

Comment: Perhaps I should have mentioned this earlier, but I was following [this tutorial](http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial24/tutorial24.html); it's probably not very noticeable in [his example](http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/tutorial24.jpg). I'll report it to the author.

Comment: Thanks a ton :) Very excited about this. I will look into cascaded shadow maps soon; I'm going to need something very efficient for what I'm doing. Hopefully it works well with Deferred Shading...I'll probably need that too. One step at at time :) ([one more screenie](http://i.imgur.com/yTgp6.png))

Comment: Nice shots, looking good! Shadow mapping doesn't necessarily affect deferred shading all that much depending on how it's done. Deferred shading itself is pretty simple with the hard part being how to pack the buffers for efficient memory use and transfer. Deferred shading itself is relatively expensive when there's not much to do, but relatively cheap when there's a lot to do, so YMMV depending on the complexity of your assets and rendering pipeline.

Answer (score 2):

This is called the "deer in headlights" effect of buffer mapped shadows. There are a several ways to minimize this effect. Look for "light space shadow mapping".

Comment: Is that not what I'm doing? I first compute the shadow map by drawing the scene from the perspective of the light, and then when I do my final render pass, I use that same light projection matrix so that I can figure out where a pixel is in the shadow map.

Comment: @Mark: No. You're drawing the view from the light, but in world space. The idea is to generate the shadow map in a way, that its spatial resolution gets more evenly distributed in the final step. Just gooogle for this subject. First hit: http://www.cg.tuwien.ac.at/research/vr/lispsm/

Comment: Last updated 2006. Nothing's changed since then? Wish there was a tutorial that described the method rather than a bunch of source code to dig through and decipher. Oh... nvm. There's a paper. I'll try to read that tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: @Mark: Well, this pretty much got rid of nasty jagged edges artifacts. Ever since then, the interest was on drawing soft shadows. There's tons of stuff out there. A google search for "shadow mapping paper" will yield a lot of interesting results. I recommend reading the papers published by Crytek.

Comment: [link](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache:gG7ELVe6tCUJ:developer.download.nvidia.com/assets/gamedev/docs/ShadowMaps_CEDEC_E.pdf+&hl=en&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESgeqkTW3FimsiRfHOpUEtCNMAZT-fzPOlWH_YZ4dx5vAhx304bAw8gSYznH3vVMUBu_0Zff_fwYZ-K_S4jLKZjeB6FNjfV7Rcs1Nk7KjQQYyx9m2SeNeMAEg0pqL42WOmA3nkdJ&sig=AHIEtbQ6OS2Edy6yqmjkA5TBq8tl_UqZYQ&pli=1) if you read slides 64 and 65... the "deer in headlights" problem sounds like the opposite of what I'm experiencing here. The light and camera are nearly aligned in my images (miner's lamp), which is optimal according to these slides.

Answer (score 1):

[NVidia OpenGL SDK](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/SDK/10.5/opengl/samples.html) has "cascaded shadow maps" example. You might want to check it out (haven't used it myself, though).

> How to improve the quality of my shadows?

The problem could be caused by using incorrect matrix while rendering shadows. Your example doesn't demonstrate how light matrices are set. By murphy's law I'll have to assume that bug lies in this missing piece of code - since you decided that this part isn't important, it probably causes the problem. If matrix used while testing the shadow is different from matrix used to render the shadow, you'll get exactly this problem.

I suggest to forget about the whole minecraft thing for a moment, and play around with shadows in simple application. Make a standalone application with floor plane and rotating cube (or teapot or whatever you want), and debug shadow maps there, until you get hang of it. Since you're willing to throw +100 bounty onto the question, you might as well post the complete code of your standalone sample here - if you still get the problem in the sample. Trying to stick technology you aren't familiar with into the middle of working(?) engine isn't a good idea anyway. Take it slow, get used to the technique/technology/effect, then integrate it.

Comment: I'll take a look at that paper. Looks easier to read than the others I've seen. It's a lot of work to set up a minimal example...lot of code has to go into place before you can even start playing with the shadows. Nevertheless...perhaps I'll try it and see if I have the same problem. The light matrix should be exactly the same...I'm using the same variable; I suspect it would be much further off if I mucked it up.

Comment: @Mark: "It's a lot of work to set up a minimal example" One way is to grab some existing "GLSL tutorial" off the net and use it as a base for minimal example. Also, assumming you have classes or routines for dealing with shaders, you should be able to copy-paste minimal example (using parts of current engine) roughly within hour. In situation like this it helps to use SDL or GLUT and have "minimal opengl application" nearby.

Comment: I'm using C# and OpenTK. I'll piece something together though. Will report back in a few days.